# "get to" = "do" in context

Tags: word-usage

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/T-HGdc8L-7w?t=1100)

> this is no good.
> Because this works for two, but eventually
> I'm going to want to have a hundred.
> And I'm going to **get to** that in a future video.

I guess it means that the speaker will demonstrate how to draw 100 circles in a future video.

Does the following sentence convey the same idea?

> ... I'm going to **do** that in a future video.

In other words, "get to" and "do" are interchangeable in this context.  Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Get to" something means "reach that place or stage" in a process or journey. It can be used literally:

> We will get to Berlin on Tuesday and Moscow on Friday.

Or as in the example:

> [I've reached the stage where I can draw two circles]. I will get to [the stage of drawing 100 circles] in a future video.

You can use "going to" synonymously:  "I'm going to [draw 100 circles] in a future video".